# Flickr API retrieve stats with script without users needing to login

Tags: api, authentication, cron, flickr

Is there any way to grab Flickr API stats info without a script needing to login using OAuth every time it accesses the API? I envisage running a cron job that outputs the data I need into a file every week/month and displaying the contents of that file, however I'm not sure how I'd give the cron job script access to Flickr API persistently.

Comment: I had worded this question in a clumsy fashion, but what I really want to know is the above!

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about the same use case this morning. Periodically fetch photo stats from the API with a script. I dont think its possible as Flickr only seems to support "3-legged authentication" (that is they require a users login credentials to obtain the access token).

If flickr *had* supported a simpler form of Oauth (or Oauth2) it would only require you to ask for a request token, exchange it for an access token with your token credentials (apikey, secret).